# C# function that waits for serial port ready before reading

Tags: c#

I have a system in which I read the serial port from a X,Y,Z motion stage, meaning that I send a signal (via usb) to a function which reads the signal, moves a stepper motor accordingly, then reads the next stepper motor signal and so on. At the moment, this function looks like this:

```
 public void SCPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string sCurString = "";
                //Loop to receive the data from serial port
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(150);
                sCurString = SCPort.ReadExisting();
                if (sCurString != "")
                    StrReceiver = sCurString;
                if (BlnSet == true)
                {
                    if (StrReceiver.Length == 3)
                    {
                        if (StrReceiver.Substring(StrReceiver.Length - 3) == "OK\n")
                            BlnReadCom = true;
                    }
                    else if (StrReceiver.Length == 4)
                    {
                        if (StrReceiver.Substring(StrReceiver.Length - 3) == "OK\n" || StrReceiver.Substring(StrReceiver.Length - 4) == "OK\nS")
                            BlnReadCom = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (StrReceiver.Substring(StrReceiver.Length - 3) == "OK\n" || StrReceiver.Substring(StrReceiver.Length - 4) == "OK\nS" ||
                            StrReceiver.Substring(StrReceiver.Length - 5) == "ERR1\n" || StrReceiver.Substring(StrReceiver.Length - 5) == "ERR3\n" ||
                            StrReceiver.Substring(StrReceiver.Length - 5) == "ERR4\n" || StrReceiver.Substring(StrReceiver.Length - 5) == "ERR5\n")
                            BlnReadCom = true;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (StrReceiver.Substring(StrReceiver.Length - 1, 1) == "\n")
                        BlnReadCom = true;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Failed to receive data", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
        }
```

This function reads the serialport SCPort, every 150ms indicated by the Thread.Sleep. If I try to read the data any faster, I get the exception (which is likely an indication of the limitation of my system). Fine. However, this exception is not thrown immediately, but every once in a while. What I would like to do instead of waiting a fixed time between reading the signal, is to each time wait until the serialport is ready and then read it. This should speed up my system, as instead of waiting 150ms between every movement, I could wait exactly the amount of time the system requires.

The question is: how do I implement this behavior in the function?

I have not tried to solve it on my own, because I really have no idea about how to do this. Will be happy to implement this into my function, but at a bare minimum I need to be pointed in the right direction.

Comment: do you mind formatting your code, so it's easier for us to read?

Comment: I am new to the forum. Not sure how, but will of course give it a try.

Comment: Is the formatting alright now?

Comment: I didn't see any loop on your code.  Actually that function only wait 150 ms, read something from SCPort and after some weird checks put a flag to true (but not to false if somethings goes wrong)

Comment: Apparently, you attached the `SCPort_DataReceived` method to the `DataReceived` event of the serial port. Therefore it is called whenever data is available. Do not wait in this function, as this will delay the reception of data and eventually (if there's a lot of data) data will be lost.

Comment: @J.Salas the functions is looped using

SCPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataREceivedEventHandler(SCPort_DataReceived);

Comment: @PMF that is exactly what I want to achieved. You are correct that it will pass data whenever serialport is available. However, reducing the sleep time of the thread will cause the exception (more frequently the less it waits). That is the issue I am trying to solve.

Comment: Perhaps another possible solution would be to find the minimum amount of time the thread needs to sleep before reading, so that the thread is sleeping different amounts of time between each event. Is there an easy way of doing this?

Comment: What exception and error message are you getting exactly?

Comment: @PMF the exception is "Failed to receive data", indicating that variable sCurString is empty.

Comment: According to the documentation, `ReadExisting()` only throws an exception if the port is not open. It should never have no data to read there, either. I believe you're doing something wrong elsewhere. Please edit your question and include details about how you open and handle the serial port.

Comment: @PMF see answer with additional code.

Comment: You should _edit_ your question to include the additional details (see the small link below the tags), not add additional information as answer. That aside: Your main method exits immediately after opening the port and sending a request. So when the callback is invoked, it is very likely that the main program has already ended. You should check some tutorials on threading and events.

Comment: @PMF sorry about the edit. I have tried to make it work using separate threads but haven't gotten it to work. Where does it exit after opening the port? And to what does "callback" refer? Not sure how to solve this issue. Any advice would be helpful.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is going to be difficult, because apparently you are lacking some elementary knowledge for the task you where given. Therefore I'm not blaming you, but this code just needs a full rewrite, and that's possible in a number of ways. Even if I made a proposal, I wouldn't be sure whether it matches your use case best and whether you would be able to understand and maintain it. You should first try to understand some basic concepts such as delegates, asynchronous callbacks, and event handlers (which honestly, are not really beginner topics)

Comment: Understood and appreciated. Granted I am a beginner and I am trying to solve a problem way above my pay grade. If you have any input on how I could at least implement a behaviour in which the thread sleep time is not fixed but depends on the size of data being transferred, it would be greatly appreciated. Otherwise I will look for workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

This function handles connection to the port SCPort.

```
public void ConnectPort(short sPort)
        {
            if (SCPort.IsOpen == true)
            {
                ClosePort();
                buttonConnectStage.Text = "Connect stage";
            }
            else if (SCPort.IsOpen == false)

            {
                SCPort.PortName = comStage.SelectedItem.ToString();           //Set the serial port number
                SCPort.BaudRate = 9600;                                //Set the bit rate
                SCPort.DataBits = 8;                                   //Set the data bits
                SCPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;                        //Set the stop bit
                SCPort.Parity = Parity.None;                           //Set the Parity
                SCPort.ReadBufferSize = 2048;
                SCPort.WriteBufferSize = 1024;
                SCPort.DtrEnable = true;
                SCPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
                SCPort.ReceivedBytesThreshold = 1;
                SCPort.RtsEnable = false;

                //This delegate should be a trigger event for fetching data asynchronously, it will be triggered when there is data passed from serial port.
                SCPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(SCPort_DataReceived);     //DataReceivedEvent delegate

                try
                {
                    SCPort.Open();                                     //Open serial port
                    if (SCPort.IsOpen)
                    {
                        StrReceiver = "";
                        BlnBusy = true;
                        BlnSet = false;
                        SendCommand("?R\r");                           //Connect to the controller
                        Delay(250);
                        BlnBusy = false;

                        if (StrReceiver == "?R\rOK\n")
                        {
                            displayValues();
                            BlnConnect = true;                        //Connected successfully  
                            ShrPort = sPort;                          //Setial port number
                            buttonConnectStage.Text = "Disconnect stage";
                            SendCommand("V" + sSpeed.ToString() + "\r");            //Set speed
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            BlnBusy = false;
                            BlnConnect = false;
                            buttonConnectStage.Text = "Failed to connect";
                            MessageBox.Show("Failed to connect", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
            }
        }
```